# Copying data from a table in Oracle DB to another DB table with similar schema

Tags: database, oracle

I have a requirement to copy around 40k rows from a table in a Oracle DB to another table in different DB.

And since I have to do this daily what are the best ways we can do this in less amount of time.

One of the option we are thinking about is using DB links

Comment: Are the databases on the same host or different hosts? If different host, what sort of network is in place between them? Are you coping an entire table, or is 40k just a subset of rows? Is the target table empty, or is it populated?

Comment: @BobC host are different but within same firewall.sourcedb is a view & we are copying all data and the target will be empty

Comment: Do you actually need to copy or just access them from the 2nd db?

Comment: We have to copy and use the data from our table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

40K is a low number of rows and so dblinks will work fine.  If you are copying 100s of millions of rows then you would have to use other methods.

Also you can do an export (exp) of the table, and then import (imp) on the target using the fromuser and touser parameters.

You can also use datapump instead of export.

Comment: If data grows to 100k how will be the performance using dblinks. And is copying to a file using spool better option than copying to a db.

Comment: You also need to consider the view that produces the 40k rows. How complex is that view? Essentially what I am getting at is, what is going to be your bottleneck? i. Retrieving the rows? ii. Transporting them? iii. Writing them?

Comment: 100k will still be fine.  Once you start going millions of rows, then you have to move away from dblinks especially if it's over a congested network.  Spooling to multiple insert statements will always be slower than a direct copy or export/import. Single inserts are bad anyway; you must use the bulk loading mechanism.